# C++ : expression must be a modifiable lvalue then undefined reference to class

Tags: c++

So basically at first I wanted to change the value of CSubject "AE" with the use of a `get` method but, after seeing some documentation about it, doing this will cause errors like "expression must be a modifiable lvalue". So it's not possible to do such thing .

For something similar we can use a `set` method in this case, so that's what I did.

However, after compiling I keep geeting an error saying:

> Undefined reference to CSubject::CSubject`

Why is that?

```cpp
class CSubject
{
public:
    CSubject() = default;
    CSubject(std::string m_Name,unsigned m_SubjNr);
    void setName(std::string m_Name){ Name= m_Name;}
    std::string getName(){return Name;}

private:
    unsigned SubjNr;
    std::string Name;
};
    
int main()
{
    CSubject a("test",3); 
    a.setName("Testing");
        
    cout << a.getName();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *declared* a `CSubject` constructor taking a `std::string` and an `unsigned` argument but have never provided an actual *definition* for it! Thus, the *linker* fails when that (used) constructor is not present in the compiled code.

To fix this, either add an 'inline' definition of that constructor, as shown here (using an *initializer list* for brevity):

```cpp
class CSubject {
public:
    CSubject() = default;
    CSubject(std::string m_Name, unsigned m_SubjNr) : SubjNr{ m_SubjNr }, Name{ m_Name } {}
    void setName(std::string m_Name) { Name = m_Name; }
    std::string getName() { return Name; }

private:
    unsigned SubjNr;
    std::string Name;
};
```

Or, keeping your class declaration as it is, you can provide an 'out-of-body' definition of the constructor, elsewhere in the code, like this (here using 'old-style' long-hand member initialization):

```cpp
CSubject::CSubject(std::string m_Name, unsigned m_SubjNr)
{
    Name = m_Name;
    SubjNr = m_SubjNr;
}
```

Use one or the other, but not both!

Comment: Incidentally, though it has no real impact on your code, it is 'conventional' to use the `m_xxx` names for the *members* and other names (like `Xxx`) for the arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . My bad I forgot to copy the declaration of my constructor in this test program . However I do have a question concerning the getMethod . I tried to use `std::string& getName(){return Name;}` then called it in main  `AE.getName() = "testing"` and it worked correctly but when I wrote get SubjNr() function and called it in main `AE.getSubjNr() = 5`  it doesn't work . Why is that ?

Comment: @Upgrade You are essentially misusing the nature of a "getter" function; these are normally defined as `const` references, like `const std::string& getName() const { return Name; }` But, without seeing your getter/setter for the `SubjNr` member, it's difficult to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I know that I'm misusing the nature of a "getter" function but just wanted to know why it's not woking the same as the string getter : `int &getNr(){return SubjNr;}` in class then in main prog  `CSubject AE("test",3); AE.getNr() = 5;`

Comment: @Upgrade You have a type mismatch: `getNr()` returns a reference to an `int` but `SubjNr` is `unsigned`.